# Big Query table partitions count limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am currently working with Big Query and understand that there is a partition limit of up to 4,000 partitions.

Does anyone know if this limit apply to ***Active Storage Tier*** only or both ***Active & Long Term Storage Tier***?

Reason for asking because I have a partitioned table, partitioned by hour and have been using it for more than 6 months already but we don't get any error prompting partition limit exceed 4,000 when we insert new data.

I have did a count on the number of partition attached image below:

[image]

As we can see the total partitions is **6,401** and we are still able to insert new data.

At the same we also create a new partitioned table and try moving data into this newly created partitioned table but we encountered some error saying we have exceeded the limit of 4,000.

[image]

In addition, I also tried to insert data incrementally but I still get error as follow:

[image]

**Steps to reproduce error:**

1. Create a partitioned table (partition by hour)
2. Start moving data by month from another table

**My finding:**

The mentioned partition limit is only applicable to active storage tier.

Can anyone help to confirm on this?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the limitation, you can't *modify* more than 4000 partitions in one job. Your jobs that you describe first are supposedly working because they are modifying only a few partitions.
When you try to move more than 4000 partitions in one go, you will hit the limitation as you described.

I noticed I was hitting this limitation on both Active Storage and Long Term Storage. This is a BigQuery-wide limitation.

Comment: As mentioned, I move the data by month assuming the month has 31 days and partition by hour then 31 days * 24 hours = 744 partitions which mean that I am not inserting more than 4000 partition at one go.